# When following SenseNet installation from web deployment package for IIS8 the launch portal does not come up?

Tags: installation, iis-8, sensenet

I am having trouble installing the [SenseNet webpi](http://sensenet.codeplex.com/releases/view/624890) on our Windows Server 2012 RS. I follow the steps from http://wiki.sensenet.com/How_to_install_Sense/Net_from_web_deployment_package_(IIS_7.5_and_IIS_7.0). I have attempted to do the installation 4 times all with the same result. When I browse site from IIS which is Step 9 the site does not load and instead results in an error. Has anyone had similar issues or knows what I may be missing?

Comment: You will get no help here without the error message.

Comment: Do you get any errors on step #8?